# Flutter Staggered Grid View cannot pass variable - Undefined name 'viewModel'

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

I am getting an error `Undefined name 'viewModel'` when I am trying to build a Staggered Grid View and pass a variable to the Material class:

```
  Material Items(String heading) {
    return Material(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            if (heading ==
                ('Text')) {
                  showMainDialog(context, viewModel); <- The error is here: Undefined name 'viewModel'
            }
          },
        ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     body: SingleChildScrollView(child: loadMainPage(viewModel)),
  }

  Widget loadMainPage(ViewModel viewModel) {
    return StaggeredGridView.count(
        children: <Widget>[
          Items(
              ('Text')
            ),
        ],
        staggeredTiles: [
          StaggeredTile.extent(1, 150.0),
        ],
      );
  }

  showMainDialog(BuildContext context, ViewModel viewModel) {

    Dialog simpleDialog = Dialog(
        ...
    showDialog(
        context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) => simpleDialog);
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Below is the full code for the `Widget loadMainPage` and the `Material` Class, which I believe are missing a additional forwarder or something.

The error is: `Error: The getter 'viewModel' isn't defined for the class '_MainPageState'.`

```
Material Items(IconData icon, String heading, Color cColor) {
    return Material(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            if (heading ==
                ('Text')) {
                  showMainDialog(context, viewModel); <- The error
            } else if (heading ==         ^^^^^^^^^
                ('Text1')) {
                  showMainDialog(context, viewModel); <- The error
            }                             ^^^^^^^^^
          },
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              child:
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          child: Icon(
                            icon,
                            color: cColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(    
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:10),
                          child: Text(
                            heading,
                            softWrap: true,
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  Widget loadMainPage(ViewModel viewModel) {
    return StaggeredGridView.count(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 12.0,
        mainAxisSpacing: 12.0,
        children: <Widget>[
          Items(
              Icons.add,
              ('Text'),
              Colors.green),
          Items(
              Icons.add,
              ('Text1'),
              Colors.red),
        ],
        staggeredTiles: [
          StaggeredTile.extent(1, 150.0),
          StaggeredTile.extent(1, 150.0),
        ],
      );
  }
```

Comment: can you include full sample widget,

Comment: It's very long, that's why I have provided only the code snapshot where I think the problem lies. For some reason the `Widget loadMainPage` cannot pass the `viewModel` to the `Material` class. The `Widget loadMainPage` and the `Material` Class are provided with the full code. I think I should add some more code in `Widget loadMainPage` to pass the  variable...

Comment: try to check your brackets , it might be the issue

Comment: Brackets are correct, I could have deleted or missed to delete some when shortening the code, but in the original code the brackets are fine. I think there should be some additional code like this `staggeredTileBuilder: (viewModel) => StaggeredTile.fit(1),` but I cannot seem to get it working.

Comment: Provided the full Widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the instance as a parameter, like

```dart
Material Items(ViewModel viewModel , IconData icon, String heading, Color cColor) {
```

And pass instance like

```dart
       Items( viewModel,
              Icons.add,
              ('Text'),
              Colors.green),
```

I will suggest using named parameter instead of positional.

Comment: This would work if I needed to pass the `viewModel` to the `Items` but I actually need to pass it to another object in: `showMainDialog(context, viewModel)`

Comment: I am still  little confused , `Material Items(String heading) {` can you rename and provide model here

Comment: `Material Items` is building the items to display to the user. Instead I need to pass the `viewModel` to `showMainDialog` which is a different function making use of it (and I don't need to display it to the user).

Comment: Turned out your suggestion works very well! I was a bit confused with the usage of the 4 instances in `Material Items` at first. Thanks for the help!